# unable to run my android application

Tags: android

I am trying to establish a chatting application between a server and a client, but the application could not run because of this line of code : message = (String) input.readObject(); 
because at first, inputStream is null ! any one can help please ? here is my code

```
package com.example.test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OptionalDataException;
import java.net.Socket;


import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button send;
    private Button connect;
    private EditText userText;
    private TextView chatWindow;

    private String serverIP;
    private ObjectOutputStream output;
    private ObjectInputStream input;
    private String message = "";
    private Socket connection;

    @SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "NewApi", "NewApi" })
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
          }

        serverIP = "192.168.1.4";
        //userText.setEnabled(false);
        send = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        connect = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        chatWindow =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
        userText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1); 
        userText.setHint("Enter your message here");

        connect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {


                //connect to the server
                try{
                    connectToServer();
                    setupStreams();

                }catch(EOFException eofException){
                    showMessage("\n client terminated the connection");
                }catch(IOException ioException){
                    ioException.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String message = userText.getText().toString();
                sendMessage(message);
                userText.setText("");   

            }
        });

        while(true){
            try{
                message = (String) input.readObject(); 
                showMessage("\n" + message + " NULL ");
                chatWindow.refreshDrawableState(); 
            }catch(ClassNotFoundException classNotFoundException){
                showMessage("\n I don't know that object type");
            }
            catch(NullPointerException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (OptionalDataException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    } // end of onCreate


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    //connect to the server
        private void connectToServer() throws IOException {
            showMessage("Attempting connection... \n");
            connection = new Socket( "192.168.1.4", 6789);
            showMessage("Connected to " + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName() );
        }

        //setup streams to send and receive messages
        private void setupStreams() throws IOException{
            output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            output.flush();
            input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            showMessage("\n Your streams are now good to go! \n ");
        }

        //whileChatting with server
        private void whileChatting() throws IOException{

                try{
                    message = (String) input.readObject(); 
                    showMessage("\n" + message + " NULL ");
                    chatWindow.refreshDrawableState(); 
                }catch(ClassNotFoundException classNotFoundException){
                    showMessage("\n I don't know that object type");
                }

        }

        //close the streams and sockets
        private void closeCrap(){
            showMessage("\n closing crap down");
            ableToType(false);
            try{
                output.close();
                input.close();
                connection.close();
            }catch(IOException ioException){
                ioException.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        // gives user permission to type into the text box
        private void ableToType(final boolean tof){
            userText.setEnabled(tof);
        }

        // send messages to server
        private void sendMessage(String message){
            try{
                output.writeObject("CLIENT - " + message);
                output.flush();
                showMessage("\nCLIENT - " + message);
            }catch(IOException ioException){
                chatWindow.append("\n somethine messed up sending message!");
            }
        }

        //change/update chatWindow
        private void showMessage(final String m){
            chatWindow.append(m);
            chatWindow.refreshDrawableState();
        }

} // end of class MainActivity
```

Comment: or better yet, go to line 95 in your MainActivity.java onCreate() method and make sure the var on that line has a value.

Comment: Line 95 is : message = (String) input.readObject();

Comment: Are you sure input is not null?

Comment: input is an ObjectInputStream ! so I am waiting a message from the server and that message will be the ObjectInputStream . So at first it is null yes! So what can I do ?!

Comment: post your code. And initialize the object.

Comment: You need to connect to the server and get the value in a background thread then update the variable once the server returns the value, if ever

Comment: I have posted my code

Answer (score 2):

Your code is definitely not following any good UI guidelines: You are doing network operations on the Main (UI) Thread, *and* you have an infinite loop in `onCreate()`. Android should actually offer to force close your app if nothing crashes. Now, a *likely* cause for the `null` problem you are facing:

`setupStreams()` is only called upon a button click. However, your `while (true)` loop is in the root of `onCreate()`. This means that as soon as the click listeners are made and set, the loop runs, attempts to read in from `input` and fails since `setupStreams()` hasn't been called.

So please don't do away with StrictMode - it's there to *help*, and thing about your code from an event driven standpoint ("Once X happens, then do Y"). And also get rid of loops in the Main (UI) Thread. Loops are fine for Console windows, but with UIs (which have their own complex lifecycle), you can't do this without freezing a lot of things.

Answer (score 1):

Do all of your network tasks in `doInBackground()` of`AsyncTask` then update your `UI` variables in `onPostExecute()`. Something like

```
 public class TalkToServer extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    //do your work here
        return something;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
           // do something with data here-display it or send to mainactivity
}
```

Here is the documentation on **[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)**

Another thing to consider is you are using the variable `message` in different places which may cause you problems. It looks like you have it defined as a member variable then as a local variable to other methods. You don't want to re-use the same variable name this way. Don't define `String message` multiple times in the same `Activity`

Comment: Although this is the right way, this shouldn't be the problem on account of: `StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();`

Comment: @A--C thanks, I haven't used that. I guess I need to check into that. I will delete the answer if you think I should

Comment: As I searched, StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build() is the solution replacement for AsyncTask. Isn't it ?

Comment: I would say  don't, the barebones `AsyncTask` is good for getting the OP in the right direction. But deleting is up to you.

Comment: @WassiMZgheiB not a "solution", but rather a dirty hack IMO. You're subverting the very thing that gives you a hint on how to do stuff correctly with regards to app development.

Comment: @A--C ok, thanks for the help and I will look into that as I haven't used it and I think the suggestion of not reusing variable names is important.

Comment: I will have to refer to A--C about the "solution" because I have never used it but I have always known to use a background task for networking things and not run them on the `UI`

Comment: @codeMagic, this code works well between two computers and the chatting application was done without any problems, so the variable name is not the issue in the code, it is that the inputStream when the application runs is null. It is weird how two devices running java do not face such problem, however when it comes to android application, the error occurs !

Comment: @WassiMZgheiB I understand that the variable names are probably not this issue and that the inputstream is null. However, I was just giving some added advice as it is, IMO, bad practice for a naming convention. It can cause problems and you may want to consider not re-using the same name...especially when one is a member variable. I would try A--C's answer because it has been my experience that he has provided a lot of good advice on here and A--C looks to be right again :)

Comment: @codeMagic Ah okay thanks I appreciate that ! So as a conclusion what should I modify in my code? Should I try AsyncTask or what?

Comment: @WassiMZgheiB I would suggest implementing `AsyncTask` to do your network stuff but also see A--C's answer and implement his suggestions as well. Both answers, I believe, will make your program more efficient and should help to get it working

Comment: @WassiMZgheiB Keep in mind that our guidelines might break your code at first while you implement everything. As a dev don't be afraid to refactor your code to make it better, even if it means some other crashes along the way.

Comment: Good point A--C! @WassiMZgheiB you should accept A--C's answer when you can if it got you going in the right direction so others that may have the same problem can find it easily